# Recursively free a circular singly linked list?

Tags: c, recursion, free, circular-list

I'm curious what base case can be used to recursively free a circular linked list, passing the head of the linked list as the only parameter. I originally thought a base case could be `if (head->next == head) { return NULL; }` could be sufficient to prevent head->next from pointing to itself, but this doesn't seem to be the case (literally and figuratively). The last node `free(Head)` is not being freed after the recursive calls here.

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

    // temp stores the original head of the list
    node *recursive_destroyer(node *head, node *temp)
    {
        if (head->next == temp) 
            return NULL;
    
        recursive_destroyer(head->next, temp);
    
        free(head);
        head = NULL;
    
        return NULL;
    }
```

Comment: This is entirely dependent upon your implementation. What you describe should work fine, there's no reason it wouldn't.

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED Ill post the function in the post. I thought I had it working, but it seems that the head is not freeing after the recursive calls

Comment: How do you represent an empty list?

Comment: @rici I have a freeLinkedList(); function that takes care of the actual list (also have a LinkedList struct) , which frees the actual list after calling this function. I cannot get the last node freed here, in order to free the entire list

Comment: Why are you returning from `recursive_destroyer` at all if you're only going to return `NULL`? Why note make it a `void` function?

Comment: @MarkSaving I like to return NULL from all of my free functions to make sure that what's being freed is actually NULL, and in this case it isn't for some reason.

Comment: @user12787203: Returning a value from a function whose caller never uses the value doesn't ensure anything. A good rule of thumb is that the return value from a function which returns one should never be ignored, and a function whose return value will be ignored shouldn't return one (i.e. should be declared as `void`). Anything else can only confuse people, starting with the author. (You can ask GCC to verify that return values are never ignored, by the way.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You asked about passing in one parameter

I think most people skipped your first sentence, and jumped to your code. You ask in your post:

> I'm curious what base case can be used to recursively free a circular linked list, **passing the head of the linked list as the only parameter**. ...

You go on to explain the approach you tried:

> I originally thought a base case could be `if (head->next == head) { return NULL; }` could be sufficient to prevent `head->next` from pointing to itself, but this doesn't seem to be the case ...

You provide a code example, but it passes in two parameters.

#### Remove `head->next`, not `head`

This answer is addressing the question in your first sentence. A short comparison with your approach will follow.

Checking to see if `head->next` points to `head` is a fine stopping case, but it means your recursive function needs to remove and destroy `head->next` at each iteration, and then recursively process the same list.

If `head->next` and `head` are the same, then destroy `head`, and you are done.

I don't see any point of returning a value from this function, so I removed it.

```
void recursive_destroyer(node *head) {

    if (head == NULL) return;

    if (head->next == head) {
        destroy(head);
        return;
    }

    node *tmp = head->next;
    head->next = head->next->next;
    destroy(tmp);

    recursive_destroyer(head);
}
```

Notice there is no longer any need for a second parameter to the recursive function.

#### Comparison with your approach

There are some issues in your sample code that caused erroneous behavior. There are other answers that have addressed them with some depth. But, I did want to point out that you should prefer ***tail recursion*** whenever possible.

Tail recursion is a special case of a sibling call. A sibling call is when a function calls another function, and then immediately returns. In the example below, `function_A()` is making a sibling call to `function_B()`

```
void function_B () { puts(__func__); }

void function_A (bool flag) {
    if (flag) {
        function_B();
        return;
    }
    puts(__func__);
}
```

A sibling call can be optimized by the compiler to reuse the stack frame of the current function to make the sibling call. This is because none of the current function state of the caller is needed after the sibling returns.

A tail recursive call can be optimized in the same way. Thus, the tail recursive call when optimized has the same memory footprint as an ordinary loop. And in fact, if the optimizer detects the sibling call is a recursive call, instead of performing a function call to itself, the tail recursion is converted into a jump to the start of the function. Most C compilers can perform this optimization. You can manually perform this optimization yourself, and easily convert a tail recursive function into a loop.

If you are using the optimization features of your C compiler, and it supports tail recursion optimization, then there is no technical reason to prefer a loop over tail recursion. If your software team finds reading recursive code confusing, then loops are preferred just to make the code easier to comprehend.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't setting the head equal to the recursive_destroyer function inside another function that frees the entire list. Here is that function:

```
LinkedList *destroy_list(LinkedList *list)
{
    node *temp;

    if (list == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if (list->head == NULL)
        return NULL;

    temp = list->head;
    
    // was not setting list->head equal to this function.
    // causing the original head to never become NULL
    list->head = recursive_destroyer(list->head, temp);

    if (list->head != NULL)
        printf("Error, head not freed.. \n");

    free(list);

    return NULL;
}
```

Could have also passed a pointer to list->head to avoid setting list->head equal to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work. It will leave a single allocation intact.

Consider the circular linked list `[1]`. If you call `recursive_destroyer(head, head)`, it will not free anything. The correct recursive code would be

```c
void destroy_helper(node* const current, node* const original) {
    if (current->next != original) destroy_helper(current->next, original);
    free(current);
}

void destroy(node* const list) {
    // null-check necessary since otherwise current->next is UB in destroy_helper
    if (list) destroy_helper(list, list);
}
```

If we want to turn this into iterative code, we must first modify the `destroy_helper` function to be tail-recursive:

```c
void destroy_helper(node* const current, node* const original) {
    node* const next = current->next;
    free(current);
    if (next != original) destroy_helper(next, original);
}
```

which we can then rewrite to a loop:

```c
void destroy(node* const list) {
    if (list) {
        node* current = list;
        do {
            node* next = current->next;
            free(current);
            current = next;
        } while (current != list);
    }
}
```

Edit:

To prove that my code is actually freeing everything, we can replace `free` with the following function:

```c
void free_with_print(node* ptr) {
    printf("Freeing node with value %d\n", ptr->data);
    free(ptr);
}
```

A simple example:

```c
int main() {
    node* node1 = malloc(sizeof *node1);
    node1->data = 1;
    node1->next = node1;
    
    node* node2 = malloc(sizeof *node2);
    node2->data = 2;
    node2->next = node1;
    node1->next = node2;
    destroy(node1);
}
```

using the iterative version prints

```
Freeing node with value 1
Freeing node with value 2
```

as expected. Trying the same thing with your original code prints

```
Freeing node with value 1
```

As expected, your code does not free one of the two nodes, while mine frees both.

Comment: I believe that your recursive function is the same as mine, except that you are using temp to traverse through the list, and not the original head. I tried swapping these for my base case, and the result is still the same, in that the last node is still not being freed. I do have a separate function already that checks if the head is NULL already.

Comment: No, my function is not the same as yours. My function always frees the entire list. Your function will free all nodes of the list except the `node` for which `node->next` is `original`.

Comment: @user12787203 See my edit for more details.

Answer (score 0):

For code like this you can (and should) do "single step debugging" in your head to convince yourself it should work as intended. This is a very important skill to learn.

Let's try 3 cases:

a) Imagine that the list is empty (`head` and `temp` are NULL). In this case it would crash at `if (head->next == temp)` due to trying to use a NULL pointer in `head->next`.

b) Imagine that the list has one item. In this case `if (head->next == temp)` is true because it's a circular linked list, so it returns from the first invocation without freeing anything.

c) Imagine the list has 2 items. In this case `if (head->next == temp)` is false for the first invocation and true for the second invocation; so the second invocation will free nothing and the first invocation will free the original head of the list.

We can extrapolate from that and say that the last item on the list is never freed (but the first item at the original head of the list will be freed if it's not also the last item).

To fix that you could always free the item, like:

```
    if (head->next == temp) {
        free(head);
        return NULL;
    }
```

This is messy because you're duplicating code (and could invert the condition to avoid that). It would also be easier to read if `head` always points to the original head and `temp` was temporary. Also (as mentioned in comments) there's no point returning NULL when it finishes. Refactoring the code gives you something like:

```
void recursive_destroyer(node *head, node *temp)
{
    if (head->next != temp) {
        recursive_destroyer(head, temp->next);
    }
    free(temp);
}
```

However; this still crashes if the list is originally empty. To fix that I'd do a wrapper function, like:

```
void recursive_destroyer(node *head) {
    if(head != NULL) {
        recursive_destroyer_internal(head, head);
    }
}

static void recursive_destroyer_internal(node *head, node *temp)
{
```

The final problem is that recursion is bad (tends to be slower due to all the extra function calls, and has a risk of crashing when you run out of stack space, and often ends up harder for people to read); especially if/when the compiler can't do "tail call optimization" itself to convert it into a non-recursive loop. To fix that you shouldn't be using recursion. E.g.:

```
void destroy(node *head) {
    node *original_head = head;
    node *temp;

    if(head != NULL) {
        do {
            temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            free(temp);
        } while(head != original_head);
    }
}
```